# How put sql query inside ms access report?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, ms-office, office365

I need column's sum *absent* where gradeid=1 in report form.
I made this SUM([dbo_attendance]![absent]), but I can't put query for gradeid filter.

Comment: Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
=Sum([dbo_attendance]![absent]*Abs([dbo_attendance]![gradeid]=1))
```